# I may sound very dump lol - but getting everything straight in the first place is better than not to ask at all

Tags: comments, pound

Beginner with python - I am taking a class with data camp and in one exercise, I used " # " to add my comment, after running the code, the comment is not showing up I believe it should right.

Did I miss anything or is the exercise screen has a bug or something? This question is too simple, I may sound dump but rather focus on learning the basics before moving on. lol.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question isn't descriptive enough in its current state, and comes across as generally unclear. Please read through [ask] and edit your question to be more precise. Also please take our site [tour] to learn more about our format and community.

Answer (score 0):

If your line starts with the comment sign `#`, then the python interpreter will ignore this line.
So if you run these lines:

```
print("Hello earth")
# print("Hello moon")
```

The output will be only `Hello earth`

Comment: Thanks fox, I got it and ready to move on!